# jQuery preventDefault - Why is it not working?

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I have this HTML:

```
<header>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-inverse pull-left" href="myfile.html"> &larr; prev</a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">ipsum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ipsum</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a class="btn btn-inverse pull-right disabled" href="file.html">next &rarr;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

and this JS (in `document.ready` wrapper):

```
$(".disabled").bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I click on the  disabled link, I still open the next page. Why?

Comment: Can you set up a Fiddle?

Comment: It does stop the click in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Xac8G/1/ .Your sure you are attaching jQuery above this code in your page?

Comment: Just put an `alert` to check whether the handler was bound or not.

Comment: it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/qR8gK/18/

Comment: You probably have an error thrown somewhere. Errors terminate/disable the current JavaScript call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it also worked for me as a Fiddle, I knew the problem needed to be in some other part of my script. After a bit of debugging I've found the problem:

```
$(".disabled").bind('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

was set in an `on` wrapper:

```
$("#poem").on("click", function() {
  $(".disabled").bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

After writing it like this:

```
$(".disabled").bind('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
});

$("#poem").on("click", function() {
  // something...
})
```

it works now!

Comment: You're on to somehing there, now if you drop `bind()` and use `on()` for the first handler aswell, you're golden.